# How do I find out what is causing my dedicated server to continuously reboot?

Tags: windows

I rebooted my Windows 2008 dedicated server for general maintenance and shortly received an email from my hosting company (OVH) saying that the server was unresponsive and then a follow up email saying that it is the server continuously rebooting and was put into rescue mode. They then left me to it and I have received no support to my emails since this morning.

Now I have VNC access which gives me some basic tools like command line access, and I can connect via SSH - neither of which I have much experience with.

I have no recollection of installing/modifying the system in any way for it to have a problem. I would have thought this to be a hardware issue? No idea what to do, or where to start.

Please help!

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the event logs?

Comment: Wouldnt know where to look without access to the event logger